# How to find specific points/coordinates in shortest_path?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, networkx

I am using NetworkX, numpy and [sknw module](https://github.com/yxdragon/sknw) to find the `shortest_path` of a maze. Shortest path algorithm results what I want and I can draw the path with nodes. However, there are another points that I want to find on this path but they are not nodes in the shortest path. Here is the shortest path specified with just found nodes:

[image: shortest path visualized with red nodes]

Here is the what I need:

[image: marked with blue circles]

Here is the original image:

[image: cropped_image]

What is the way of finding these points and draw them as the red nodes in the image ? Here is the code (editted):

```
#Skeletonize the Thresholded Image
skel = skeletonize(threshold2)
#Build Graph from skeleton
graph = sknw.build_sknw(skel, multi=False)
G = nx.Graph(graph)
#Find the shortest path
path = nx.shortest_path(G,source=0,target=len(G)-1)
path_edges = zip(path,path[1:])
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray') 

def nodes_edges(G,n):

    for (s,e) in path_edges:
        ps = graph[s][e]['pts']
        plt.plot(ps[:,1], ps[:,0], 'green')
        # Find the "corner points" and plot:
        tolerance = 30
        simple_polyline = approximate_polygon(ps, tolerance)
        plt.plot(simple_polyline[1:-1, 1], simple_polyline[1:-1, 0], '.m')
    node = G.node
    ps = np.array([node[i]['o'] for i in path])
    plt.plot(ps[:,1], ps[:,0], 'r.')
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.show()

    print(ps)
    print('Number of Element = ',len(ps))
    print('Number of Step = ', 
    nx.shortest_path_length(G,source=0,target=len(G)-1))
    print('Path Edges = ', path_edges)
    print('Shortest Path = ', path)
    return(n)

nodes_edges(graph,skel)
```

Edit: Here is the output that provides turning points and nodes separately
[image: output]

Comment: Could you also post some code? I suspect you'd want to look for abrupt changes in direction along the path, but it helps if I had some code to tinker with.

Comment: @N.Wouda Sure, I added whole code

Comment: Great! Could you also upload `cropped_image.jpg`? You can attach this to the post just like you already did with the other two images. That should be everything we'd need.

Comment: @N.Wouda Sorry, you are right. I attached it now.

Comment: I'll have a look later today, if this question remains unanswered by then.

Comment: @N.Wouda Okay, thank you for your interest.

Comment: What is `skeletonize`? I could reconstruct most of the dependencies you have from the code, but I do not know this function. What are your imports?

Comment: @N.Wouda Sorry for the late response. `skeletonize` function belong to the module of sknw as I provided the link in the post. You can also click here to see: https://github.com/yxdragon/sknw . This code in this link is my source code. My imports are: 

`import numpy as np`
`import cv2`
`from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`
`from skimage.morphology import skeletonize`
`import sknw`
`import networkx as nx`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179249/discussion-between-ender-ayhan-and-n-wouda).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "angular" points you want to find are not defined as the "intersection" used to build the graph. Therefore, they can't be found using the same method.

Depending on what is your actual definition for those points, a method could be to simplify the path using the [Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm), using [`approximate_polygon`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#approximate-polygon) in `skimage` (see the [demo here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#approximate-polygon)). For this a tolerance parameter have to be chosen.

From the [example](https://github.com/yxdragon/sknw) given in the `sknw` readme, I tried to recreate yours:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
from skimage import data
import sknw
import networkx as nx
from skimage.measure import approximate_polygon

# open and skeletonize
img = data.horse()
ske = skeletonize(~img).astype(np.uint16)

# build graph from skeleton
graph = sknw.build_sknw(ske)

# draw image
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')

# draw edges by pts
for (s,e) in graph.edges():
    polyline = graph[s][e]['pts']
    plt.plot(polyline[:,1], polyline[:,0], 'green', alpha=.6)

    # Find the "corner points" and plot:
    tolerance = 5
    simple_polyline = approximate_polygon(polyline, tolerance)
    plt.plot(simple_polyline[1:-1, 1], simple_polyline[1:-1, 0], '.m')


# draw node by o
node, nodes = graph.node, graph.nodes()
ps = np.array([node[i]['o'] for i in nodes])
plt.plot(ps[:,1], ps[:,0], 'r.')

# title and show
plt.title('Build Graph')
plt.show()
```

which gives: (the magenta points being the "angular" points)

[image: point detection example]

I think it would work much better on the maze image.

edit, example code for iterating over a path:

```
one_path = nx.shortest_path(graph, source=0, target=8)

full_line = []
for source, target in zip(one_path, one_path[1:]):
    polyline = graph[source][target]['pts']

    # Find the "corner point":
    tolerance = 5
    simple_polyline = approximate_polygon(polyline, tolerance)
    full_line.extend(simple_polyline[:-1])

full_line.append(simple_polyline[-1]) # add the last point
full_line = np.array(full_line)  # convert to an array
```

Comment: Wow, it is working ! Thank you. Although it is not better than the horse, it provides points that I want, in deed more. However, why did it give runtime warning? please see the output and the warnings from here: https://imgur.com/a/x1hiDCZ . Also, how can I sort these points as second image in the link: https://imgur.com/a/x1hiDCZ (starting from the first node until the last node including the corner points).

Comment: @EnderAyhan  I added some code to build one unique path from enter point to exit point.  I don't get these warning... did you try to increase the tolerance?

Comment: I don't get warnings anymore. I am still working on your solution.  I put your new code into mine (post editted with your solution). It still doesn't give list as I need. Because I need to zip nodes with the turning points. Thus, path may start from the source node until the target by involving turning points in a list. Maybe I could not apply your code correctly.  Could you please insert your new code into mine by using original maze image that I provided in the post, run and see what I mean? I would be appreciate if you do that. I also attached output screenshot for clarification @xdze2